# abort error, fatal python error, Python quit unexpectedly

Tags: python

i am running this script for a tts program

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg 
import pyttsx3


layout = [ [sg.Text("Enter text to speak")],
            [sg.Input()],
            [sg.OK(), sg.Cancel()] ]


window = sg.Window('TEXT-TO-SPEECH').Layout(layout)
# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Cancel'):   # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    if event in ('OK'):
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        engine.say(values[0])
        engine.runAndWait()
        break

# read window

button, values = window.Read()
```

but the error says

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyObjCTools/AppHelper.py", line 262 in runConsoleEventLoop
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 35 in startLoop
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 192 in runAndWait
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 180 in runAndWait
  File "/Users/nivarsh/Documents/javascript-basics/tts.py", line 19 in <module>
Abort trap: 6
```

please help me in finding the way out so I can pulish this program

Comment: Your program works for me.  I needed to install the `PySimpleGUI` and `pyttsx3` modules.  Then I had an error due to missing `libespeak.so.1`, so I also had to install the `espeak` package on my system.  Maybe you are having a similar problem, so check to see if you have `espeak`, as `pyttsx3` depends on it.

Comment: where can i find espeak

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, so I got it by doing `sudo apt install espeak`.  Here is the espeak home page http://espeak.sourceforge.net/ - there are some pre-compiled binaries for various platforms on the Downloads page.

Comment: its only available for windows and linux only. I am on macos

Comment: Go to this page and look for "Compiled for MacOS X" - http://espeak.sourceforge.net/download.html